# Does reportviewer upgradation needed from vs 2005 to vs 2010 or not?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I am using reportviewer of version 8.0.0.0 in visual studio 2005 and now i had upgraded my .net application to visualstudio 2010,Does i need to upgrade my report viewer to 10.0.0.0 or the earlier vesion will work fine??
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your vs 2005 project to vs 2010, the report viewer automatically

upgraded to the new version. There is no additional coding needed.

Please Note : Please make a backup of existing project before upgrade.

Hope will help.

Comment: In my code it is showing the old version of reportviewer ie 8.0.0.0 ,Will this works fine for vs2010, or do i need to upgrade it manually?

Comment: If your report viewer control shows the version number 8.0.0.0 in the property window, you need to delete this control and drag new control in the vs 2010 tool box.